# Syncing someone else's iphone to my itunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, music

Can I sync someone else's iphone to my iTunes and put my songs on their phone without losing their imformation such as contacts

Answer (score 1):

Store the contacts in iCloud? And yes, with the new iTunes this should be possible.
You can even download all the apps from their device on your computer.
You just have to confirm with the Apple ID that you want to sync with your computer.

Comment: months too late for anyone to care - but I don't think the OP meant that; I think they just wanted to 'share' the music, with no consequences. Guess they've discovered that wouldn't work by now ;-)